# Deno post method empty request body

Tags: json, api, rest, deno, insomnia

I am currently developing a proof-of-concept REST api app with **Deno** and I have a problem with my **post method** (getAll et get working). The body of my request does **not contain data** sent with Insomnia.

**My method :**

```
addQuote: async ({ request, response }: { request: any; response: any }) => {
    const body = await request.body();
    if (!request.hasBody) {
      response.status = 400;
      response.body = { message: "No data provided" };
      return;
    }

    let newQuote: Quote = {
      id: v4.generate(),
      philosophy: body.value.philosophy,
      author: body.value.author,
      quote: body.value.quote,
    };

    quotes.push(newQuote);
    response.body = newQuote;
  },
```

**Request :**

[image: insomnia json request]

**Response :**

[image: insomnia json response]

I put `Content-Type - application/json` in the header. 
If I return only `body.value`, it's empty.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Are you using oak framework?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yes I am for the router !
`import { Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since value type is promise we have to resolve before accessing value.

**Try this:**

```
addQuote: async ({ request, response }: { request: any; response: any }) => {
    const body = await request.body(); //Returns { type: "json", value: Promise { <pending> } }
    if (!request.hasBody) {
      response.status = 400;
      response.body = { message: "No data provided" };
      return;
    }
    const values = await body.value;
    let newQuote: Quote = {
      id: v4.generate(),
      philosophy: values.philosophy,
      author: values.author,
      quote: values.quote,
    };

    quotes.push(newQuote);
    response.body = newQuote;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! The compilation fails because `result` doesn't exist. I replaced by `body` and it works!

Comment: Worked. Same thing `await` was missing in my `body.value`;